# How can I install libdouble-conversion-dev on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-18.04

I tried installing the **libdouble-conversion-dev** package using `sudo apt-get install libdouble-conversion-dev` but failed with the following output:

```
Package libdouble-conversion-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libdouble-conversion-dev' has no installation candidate
```

I have also tried running `sudo apt-get update` beforehand and got the same results, as well as installing from the debian file from https://packages.debian.org/buster/amd64/libdouble-conversion-dev/download but nothing seemed to have changed.

Comment: How did you install the Debian package and what do you mean with "nothing seemed to have changed"?

Comment: I installed it by clicking on the file but I just tried installing it again using the command line and it works now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually install a Debian package on a compatible Ubuntu host with `sudo dpkg -i $name_of_package_file`.